# Apparatus for Arabic edition using Eledmac: problem in lemma direction

Tags: xetex, eledmac

I'm trying to do an edition of an Arabic text using Eledmac. The lemma in the text gets put back to front in the apparatus (specifically, the first two words in the upper apparatus).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\setmainfont{Scheherazade}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script = Arabic,Scale=1.8]{Scheherazade} 

\usepackage{eledmac}

\footparagraph{A}
\footparagraph{B}

\setcounter{firstlinenum}{5} 
\setcounter{linenumincrement}{5}

\begin{document}
\setstretch{1.6}

\lineation{page}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\begin{Arabic}

٢٨- الرابع الجزئيّ كما يقال على المعنى المذكور المسمّى بالحقيقيّ، فكذلك قد يقال على كلّ أخصّ  
\edtext{\begin{Arabic} تحت اعمّ \end{Arabic}}{\Afootnote{\textarabic{ تحت الأعمّ } R}}
 ويسمّى الجزئيّ الإضافيّ، وهو أعمّ من الأوّل، لأنّ كلّ جزئيّ حقيقيّ
\edtext{حقيقيّ}{\Bfootnote{\textarabic{ من كاتبي ويوجد أيضا في الخونجي في كتابه كشف الاسرار وهل البرنامج يمشي الآن.وإذا كتبت هنا هل السطر ممدودة؟}}}
  فهو جزئيّ إضافيّ  
\LR{\edtext{ بدون العكس}{\Afootnote{\textarabic{دون} S T,}}}
. أمّا الأوّل فلاندراج كلّ شخص تحت ماهيّته المعرّاة عن المشخّصات،
\LR{\ledsidenote{23b S}}
 وأمّا الثاني فلجواز كون الجزئيّ الإضافيّ كلّيّا، وامتناع 
\LR{\edtext{كون}{\Afootnote{\textarabic{أن يكون} R}}}
 الجزئيّ الحقيقيّ كذلك.  وهذا محاولتي لتحليل المشكلات.  وانا
 \edtext{حقيقيّ}{\Bfootnote{\textarabic{ من كاتبي ويوجد أيضا في الخونجي في كتابه كشف الاسرار وهل البرنامج يمشي الآن.وإذا كتبت هنا هل السطر ممدودة؟}}}
  اريد ان افهم هل البرنامج يستطيع ان يكتب معي؟

\end{Arabic}
\pend

\end{document}
```

Comment: Although the author of this package can be found here every few weeks, you will get a quicker response if you report issues on the project's [GitHub page](https://github.com/maieul/ledmac).

Answer (score 1):

Please, next time use the `eledmac` tag.

The begin{arabic} should be arround the pstart and not inside.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage{setspace,ragged2e}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\setmainfont{Scheherazade}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script = Arabic,Scale=1.8]{Scheherazade} 
\setfootnoteRL
\usepackage{eledmac}

\footparagraph{A}
\footparagraph{B}

\setcounter{firstlinenum}{5} 
\setcounter{linenumincrement}{5}

\begin{document}
\setstretch{1.6}

\lineation{page}
\begin{Arabic}
\beginnumbering

\pstart


٢٨- الرابع الجزئيّ كما يقال على المعنى المذكور المسمّى بالحقيقيّ، فكذلك قد يقال على كلّ أخصّ  ss
\edtext{تحت اعمّ}{\Afootnote{\textarabic{ تحت الأعمّ } R}}
 ويسمّى الجزئيّ الإضافيّ، وهو أعمّ من الأوّل، لأنّ كلّ جزئيّ حقيقيّ
\edtext{حقيقيّ}{\Bfootnote{\textarabic{ من كاتبي ويوجد أيضا في الخونجي في كتابه كشف الاسرار وهل البرنامج يمشي الآن.وإذا كتبت هنا هل السطر ممدودة؟}}}
  فهو جزئيّ إضافيّ  
{\edtext{ بدون العكس}{\Afootnote{\textarabic{دون} S T,}}}
. أمّا الأوّل فلاندراج كلّ شخص تحت ماهيّته المعرّاة عن المشخّصات،
\LR{\ledsidenote{23b S}}
 وأمّا الثاني فلجواز كون الجزئيّ الإضافيّ كلّيّا، وامتناع 
{\edtext{كون}{\Afootnote{\textarabic{أن يكون} R}}}
 الجزئيّ الحقيقيّ كذلك.  وهذا محاولتي لتحليل المشكلات.  وانا
 \edtext{حقيقيّ}{\Bfootnote{\textarabic{ من كاتبي ويوجد أيضا في الخونجي في كتابه كشف الاسرار وهل البرنامج يمشي الآن.وإذا كتبت هنا هل السطر ممدودة؟}}}
  اريد ان افهم هل البرنامج يستطيع ان يكتب معي؟


\pend

\endnumbering
\end{Arabic}
\end{document}
```